# how to create html element using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create html element using JavaScript

```
<p id="user1" class="user-list-follow">
   <img src="../images/pictures/1s.jpg" alt="img">
   <strong>User One<br><em>Some sample text here.</em></strong>
   <a href="#" class="follow">Follow</a>
</p>
<div class="decoration"></div>
```

Please help me.

Comment: What kind of html element? Do you mean the whole code that you have poster here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can find this information anywhere with little effort.

Comment: How is it easier to open a new question here than to spend 30 seconds googling?

Comment: Where is your research efforts?

Comment: thanks @Tanmay i do research ..... now this code is working for me for (var i = 0; i < teams.length; i++) {
          listItems += "<p class='user-list-follow'><img src='../images/pictures/1s.jpg' alt='img'><strong>"+ teams[i]['Associate_Name']+"<br><em>"+ teams[i]['member_id']+"</em></strong><a href='#' class='follow'>More</a></p><div class='decoration'></div>";
          }
         $('#ulist').html(listItems);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an HTML document, the [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) method creates the HTML element specified by tagName, or an HTMLUnknownElement if tagName isn't recognized.

```
var element = document.createElement(tagName[, options]);
```

**tagName**

A string that specifies the type of element to be created. The nodeName of the created element is initialized with the value of tagName. Don't use qualified names (like "html:a") with this method. When called on an HTML document, createElement() converts tagName to lower case before creating the element. In Firefox, Opera, and Chrome, createElement(null) works like createElement("null").

**options**(Optional)

An optional ElementCreationOptions object containing a single property named is, whose value is the tag name for a custom element previously defined using `customElements.define()`. See Web component [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement#Web_component_example) for more details.

**DEMO**

```js
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); // Create a <button> element
var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME"); // Create a text node
btn.appendChild(t); // Append the text to <button>

btn.onclick=function(e){
alert('You have clicked me..');
}
document.body.appendChild(btn); // Append <button> to <body>
```